# Columns don't update in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using a JTable with AbstractTableModel:

```
_model = new AbstractTableModel() {

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return _columns.size();
            }
            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return _data.size();
            }
            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return _data.get(row)[col];
            }

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int i) {
                return _columns.get(i);
            }
        };
```

When rows and columns change, calling table.revalidate() only shows changes to rows. Columns are exactly the same as before. Is there a way to force update for the whole table?

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change columns you should call `fireTableStructureChanged` on the model.

Comment: assuming you mean: "the model should fire" (as opposed to "some outside code should fire on behalf of the model") this is correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be

```
   @Override
                public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                    return _data.get[row][col];
                }
```

Comment: I would be if it were one 2d array, not a list of arrays.